Recommendation on how to track changes to a buffer?
I'm creating a programming language mode, and I use a background server process to parse the buffer and give me syntax highlighting, jump-to-definition, and other features. If the file/buffer is large, I would like to send only changes to the server, as I edit the buffer. Does Emacs have any infrastructure to help me do that, or do I need to diff the buffer with the previously sent buffer on my own?

Are you using lsp or are you implementing your own server?

@NickD It's my own thing. One reason for that is I want to eval chunks of code, and I don't think LSP has anything for that.

I don't think Emacs provides anything other than building blocks for a facility like this and cursory Googling did not uncover anything either. My guess is you'd have to build it, but it's just a guess.

It's diff-no-select.
There's not much to improve beyond as far as the internal functional goes, because Emacs has no way of knowing what point in the history you want to compare the current text against. So you have to track "previous" and "current" points to compare. Which in turn means you have strings from both points, so you can use something like this:
(defun diff-strings (string1 string2)
  "Compare STRING1 and STRING2 using `diff-no-select`."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer1 (generate-new-buffer "*diff-buffer1*"))
        (buffer2 (generate-new-buffer "*diff-buffer2*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer1
      (insert string1))
    (with-current-buffer buffer2
      (insert string2))
    (switch-to-buffer (diff-no-select buffer1 buffer2))))

